# How to check if you can send a message to contact via viber from a different app

Tags: android, android-contacts

You can make calls via viber to any phone as an "outcall".

I thought that using the intent query manager, I could check the listed apps that have the "ACTION_SEND" intent registered, then I could find the intersection of this set with another set, that is, the set of accounts for a given contact (fetched using ContactsContract). Thinking this would give me the apps/ways available to get in touch with the contact.

However, this isn't so, as viber registers itself as a ContactContract for all numbers in the phone. It also has send properties, so my method gives a false positive as viber being a way to get in touch with contacts via messenging, even when they don't have it installed.

Q. How do I check that a contact is available to be contacted by an EXPLICIT method, i.e through viber via messenging.